# Waiting for semaphore inside synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading

We have something like that:

```
public class TaskExecutor extends Thread {    
    private static Semaphore globalStackLocker;

    private synchronized Object popFromGlobalStack() {
        //do something
        try {
            globalStackLocker.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    //somwhere here are methods that allow to release semaphore
}
```

The idea is that I have synchronized method and I check my semaphore inside. If this semaphore is locked, this thread will be waiting for it to unlock.

The question is - while he is waiting, will the synchronized method be unlocked for other threads?

It looks like "yes" to me - one thread is still waiting, so another can try and execute this method. I, actually, found a few answers that *seem* proving this, but I want to be sure.

---

Ok, I see. What if I use .wait() instead of semaphore? It shares the same problem?

```
public class MyClass() extends Thread {
    private static Object lock;
    private synchronized void myPop() { 
        //do something with shared memory (that's why I need synchronize) 
        try { lock.wait() } catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
    } 
}
```

Can there be multiple threads waiting inside one synchronized method? Or maybe I should just use synchronized blocks instead in my method? (in "do something" part)

Comment: You can actually prove it (or not) with code instead of mere assumptions

Comment: This will probably demonstrate my lack of serious understanding around threads but ... why do you need both a `Semaphore` and synchronized method? Why isn't one or the other sufficient?

Comment: The only reason I am using semaphore here is because I had no other ideas how to keep threads waiting for stack to refill. And I (kind of) need synchronize to access shared memory in "do something".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No it won't**: other `Threads` will block on the same `TaskExecutor` instance because of the `synchronized`.

Since you have a `static Semaphore`, `synchronized` is unnecessary since your semaphore ensure a stronger constraint: threads are blocking not only on the same `TaskExecutor` but globally (as long as the semaphore is acquired/released *equivalently* to the `synchronized`)